# Highcharts - Left middle aligning stacked bar chart's tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip, react-highcharts

I'm trying to left middle align the tooltip for a stacked bar chart to look something like this
[image: Expected]

I have turned on the shared tooltip option and a custom formatter to render all the stacked bar options in a single tooltip as below
[image: Current]

I'm not sure why only the bottom most stack is the only one which is getting highlighted. And, turning on a custom positioner is getting rid of the tooltip pointer.

And, I'm having a hard time actually positioning the tooltip.
Just hoping to see if anyone has done something like this before or if there is any in-build highcharts setting to change the position by default.

Thanks :)

This is what I have so far
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-5ww676?file=/src/index.js:2018-2028

Comment: I did some changes in the `positioner` callback, is that a result that you want to achieve? https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-forked-283yhu

Comment: Hi @SebastianWędzel I don't think your changes was saved in the forked sandbox. The `positioner` callback is still commented off. Thanks..

Comment: yeah, sorry, my mistake - there is a proper link: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-forked-w8ujxt?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks :) 
It's close enough.. But, I do want to center the tooltip based on the respective bar's height as well.

Comment: I think that the problem is with your data structure - the stacked column shouldn't be defined as one series, that's why the tooltip indicates only to one point. Check this approach: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5L4dxhgr/